# Which VCS 3D modellers use?

Tags: version-control, blender, 3dsmax

Which `VCS` 3D modellers use? For instance in `Blender` or `3DsMax`.

Comment: Subversion is great with binary assets such as 3d models.

Answer (score 0):

Like any project, it is the choice of the person starting it. Subversion and git are two popular choices, each has strong points. It would be hard to say one is more popular than the other.

There are two points I would highlight in making your decision -

**Disk Usage** - multimedia projects often use large files. git is a distributed repository, that means every user checking out a copy gets the entire repository, this can lead to a lot of extra disk usage for large projects. Svn keeps all the revisions on the server and each user gets two copies of each file, one original and one working so that a comparison can be made locally.

This also extends to svn being able to checkout a subdirectory of a project, while git needs to copy the entire repo. While recent git versions can checkout a subset of working files, the whole revision history is still copied locally.

**Checking out previous revisions** - git uses a unique string to identify each revision, while svn uses a numerical sequence. This makes svn easier to just checkout the previous revision, or five revisions earlier. To get an earlier revision from git you need to list the history and copy a random string to get an earlier revision. At least when using the CLI, GUI apps can make this easier for both.

This can extend to discussions, svn users can say I have revision 125 and I have 122 to quickly know that someone is way behind or just missing one update.